# How to populate a GWT DataGrid?

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I've created a DataGrid so:

```
DataGrid<String> grid = new DataGrid<String>();
                grid.setPageSize(4);

                TextColumn<String> date = new TextColumn<String>() {
                    public String getValue(String object) {
                        return object;
                    }
                };
                grid.addColumn(date, "Date");

                TextColumn<String> time = new TextColumn<String>() {
                    public String getValue(String object) {
                        return object;
                    }
                };
                grid.addColumn(time, "Time");

                TextColumn<String> number = new TextColumn<String>() {
                    public String getValue(String object) {
                        return object;
                    }
                };
                grid.addColumn(number, "Number");
```

Now I'd like to populate it but I don't understood how to do it because I have these `String[]` and they must be splitted also:

```
textString[1]="01/01/2014;10:00;300";
textString[2]="02/02/2014;11:00;400"; ...
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**
@Sturmination I followed your hint but there is another problem for this code(assuming that splitting is done):

```
..
protected static List<Example> EXAMPLES = null;
..

public void method() {
...
EXAMPLES = Arrays.asList(new Example("01/01/2014", "10:00", "300"));
grid.setRowCount(EXAMPLES.size(), true);
grid.setRowData(0, EXAMPLES);
..
}
```

It returns this error:

```
The method setRowData(int, List<? extends String>) in the type AbstractHasData<String> is not applicable for the arguments (int, List<Example>)
```

And it suggests : `Change type of EXAMPLES to List<? extends String>` but it doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this:

```
DataGrid<String> grid = new DataGrid<String>();
grid.setPageSize(4);

TextColumn<String> date = new TextColumn<String>() {
    public String getValue(String object) {
        return object.split(';')[0];
    }
};
grid.addColumn(date, "Date");

TextColumn<String> time = new TextColumn<String>() {
    public String getValue(String object) {
        return object.split(';')[1];
    }
};
grid.addColumn(time, "Time");

TextColumn<String> number = new TextColumn<String>() {
    public String getValue(String object) {
        return object.split(';')[2];
    }
};
grid.addColumn(number, "Number");
```

A nicer approach would be to create a new Java Bean for your rows and convert your `String[]` items to a `List<Row>` of the new row objects

Comment: I have udpdated my question @Sturmination.

Comment: Your DataGrid must also be typed with the Example class: DataGrid<Example> grid = new DataGrid<Example>();

Comment: If I declare 'protected static DataGrid<Example> grid = new DataGrid<Example>();' it returns 'The method addColumn(Column<Example,?>, String) in the type AbstractCellTable<Example> is not applicable for the arguments 
 (TextColumn<String>, String)'.

Comment: You also have to type your Columns with the Example class: TextColumn<Example> number = new TextColumn<Example>() ... The getValue method will then also get a Example instance as parameter and not a String.

Comment: Ok. If I type in this way: 'Multiple markers at this line
 - The method addColumn(Column<String,?>, String) in the type AbstractCellTable<String> is not applicable for the arguments 
  (TextColumn<Example>, String)
 - The method addColumn(Column<Example,?>, String) in the type AbstractCellTable<Example> is not applicable for the 
  arguments (TextColumn<String>, String)'.

Comment: The column is a String while the row is an Object, so it doesn't accept:'The return type is incompatible with Column<Example,String>.getValue(Example)'.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String[]` in your code:

```
DataGrid<String> grid = new DataGrid<String>();

    TextColumn<String[]> date = new TextColumn<String[]>() {
        public String getValue(String[] object) {
           return object[0];
        }
    };
```

Split your strings when you add them:

```
private ListDataProvider<String[]> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String[]>();
private List<String[]> displayItems = dataProvider.getList();
...

for (String textString : textStrings) {
    displayItems.add(textString.split(";");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this, if size of you data is not huge.

**Create a class**

```
Class YourClass{    
  private String date, time, number;
  public YourClass(String date, String time, String nuber){
    this.date=date;
    this.time=time;
    this.number=number;
  }
  //getters and setters here
}
```

**Create a method to conver you values**

```
private List<YourObject> convert(String[] values){
  List<YourClass> data= new ArrayList<YourClass>();
  String date, time, number; 
  for(i=0; values.size(); i++){

    values[i] //split the string and asign values to date, time and number
    dataList.add(new YourClass(date, time, number));
  }
  return dataList;
}
```

**Add you values to DataGrid**

```
ListDataProvider<YourClass> provider= new ListDataProvider<YourClass>();
List<YourClass> dataList = new ArrayList<YourClass>();
dataList.addAll(convert(textString[]));
provider.addDataDisplay(grid);
provider.setList(dataList);
```

Then in your Columns just:

```
return object.getDate();
return object.getTime();
return object.getNumber();
```